# why is msg queue not created

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue

I am learning message queues, wrote code to create message queue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    key_t key;
    int msgid;

    key = ftok("proj", 64);
    if (key == -1) {
        perror("ftok failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("key:%x\n", key);
    //IPC_CREAT: creating message queue if not exists
    msgid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT);
    if (msgid == -1) {
        perror("msgget failed");
        printf("errno:%d\n", errno);
        if (errno == ENOENT)
            printf("No message queue exists for key and msgflg did not specify IPC_CREAT\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("msgid:%x\n", msgid);


    return 0;
}
```

Running the command did not show output: ipcs -q

```
panther2@ubuntu:~/c_codes/msg_queue$ ipcs -q

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages
```

Can you guys please tell me if i am making any mistake

Answer (score 1):

As I see there is nothing wrong with your code, but the behavior is really strange, even on my system.

As `mssget` returns 0, everything is ok ( it should return a non negative number which 0 is ) and the queue can be used.

I added a `for(;;);` at the end of your prog and start it again. `ipcs` now shows:

> 0x4025077b 0          krud       0          0            0

After I `ipcrm -q 0` and start the program again, I got a new id for each run. I now removed the endless loop and all and everything still works, every run I got a message queue with different number which I always have to destroy before next run.

That is really strange!

I found a lot reports on that topic, e.g.:
https://www.unix.com/programming/248572-msgget-2-returns-0-workaround-fix.html
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?403036-strange-problem-in-using-msgget%28%29-in-Linux

Keep us informed if you have found a valid solution!

As my system now generates at every run a new message queue with a id > 0, I can't reproduce this behavior anymore. I did not want to reboot again ;)